# Infinite nested DataGrid data template

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatable

I am developing a wpf application based on MVVM. All I am doing is trying to bind Nested DataGrids with my DataTable. I have class CustomTable

```
public class CustomTable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public List<DataTable> Main { get; set; }
        public CustomTable Child { get; set; } 
        public DataRowView _selectedItem;
        public DataRowView SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedItem;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                Child = new CustomTable();
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }  

        public CustomTable()
        {
            Main = new List<DataTable>();
            Main.Add(someRandomTable());

        }

        private DataTable someRandomTable()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
            table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
            return table;
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string caller)
        {

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
            }
        }

}
```

Custom Table consist of List of DataTables -> Main, SelectedItem, and Child of CustomTable type. I am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged to this class.

So I have ItemsControl whose DataContext is this class and ItemSource binds to Main. And My ItemControl.Template consist of DataGrid. On running it successfully displays no of DataGrids binded to each element in Main List. Now I am binding the SelectedItem property of DataGrid to SelectedItem property of CustomTable. I am able to do this also. now when I select a row and the setter of SelectedItem of customTable is called I am creating new instance of Child with predefined Main in it (For sample only, the actual logic is complex and is not related to the question).  Now I want to bind my Child to **RowDetailsTemplate** of my selectesRow so that Nested dataGrids are displayed. This should be recurssive like, clicking a row in Child's DataGrid should also display Child->Child->Main.
I am not able to achieve this and trying for last few days with no progress. Any other approach other then this is also welcomed.

**Edit**

XAML File

```
<Window x:Class="HierDataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:tvcc="clr-namespace:HierDataGrid"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:metro="http://schemas.codeplex.com/elysium">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Nested">

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Tables, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" RowDetailsTemplate="{DynamicResource Nested}" ItemsSource="{Binding Main}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>


<ScrollViewer DataContext="{Binding}">
    <StackPanel>

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TableCollection.Main}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid Name="dg" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserAddRows="False" RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource Nested}"   ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >

                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: is `TableCollection` is of type `CustomTable`?

Comment: appreciated if you could also post a picture of your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did try to make a recursive template based on some assumptions

screen shot

[image: screen]

I did some changes in your class too, implemented notification changed to `Child` property

```
    private CustomTable _child;
    public CustomTable Child
    {
        get
        {
            return _child;
        }
        set
        {
            _child = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Child");
        }
    }
```

others can be done when required

xaml

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:CustomTable}">
            <StackPanel>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Main}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                      CanUserAddRows="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
                <Expander Header="Child" Margin="10" IsExpanded="True" x:Name="child">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Child}"/>
                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Child}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="child" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding TableCollection}"/>

</ScrollViewer>
```

`l:` in above example refer to the name space to the class `CustomTable`, replace the your xaml with this. also you may remove the templates in the window resources too.

I have also restructured the templates

- Removed the named templates and created a data template for `CustomTable`.
- Used `ContentControl` to bind to `TableCollection` and WPF will resolve our defined template for the same.
- Same will apply to the `ContentControl` in the `DataTemplate` which is bound to the `Child`

so this will create a recursive template as in screen shot

you may adjust the template as per your needs. do please ask if you need any clarification.

**Row level child**

xaml

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:CustomTable}">
            <StackPanel>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Main}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid Name="dg" SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                  CanUserAddRows="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
                                <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ContentControl Margin="10"
                                                        Content="{Binding DataContext.Child, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ItemsControl,AncestorLevel=2}}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding TableCollection}"/>

</ScrollViewer>
```

result

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks very much. Your solution works very well but can you suggest me how can I show the child in the RowDetailsTemplate so that each child is directly under the parent row. Thank I lot, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: in that case you may need to restructure your data class. currently there are many rows and only one child in custom table. You need to have exactly same structure as you want to see or you expect. eg one child for every row.

Comment: I added a sample from current structure based on my assumptions.

Comment: That is why I am setting the value of my child in setter and not redefining it. My approach is When the user clicks a row-> Setter of SelectedItem will be called-> in setter define the child based on which row is clicked.

Comment: Hey, I have a few doubts related to this question about context menu. Should I ask here as an edit in my question or add a new question.

Comment: I'd suggest to post a new question if it is more than a clarification.  Post a link to question here so I can find it easily.